# Serverless framework tries to create a new S3 bucket instead of refercing an existing one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

Here's my **AWS S3** bucket inside `serverless.yml` file

```yaml
    serverlessKinesisFirehoseBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        BucketName: "${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}"
        LifecycleConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - Status: Enabled
              ExpirationInDays: 90
```

When I run

```
serverless deploy --stage dev --region eu-central-1
```

It fails with the error message:

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: serverlessKinesisFirehoseBucket (AWS::S3::Bucket)
sensor-processor-v3-dev already exists
```

That's because all S3 bucket names should be unique across all AWS regions.

**I found out that I need to reference an S3 bucket instead of creating one. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Outputs and export the S3 bucket name from old Cloudformation template and import it to other templates like below:

```
Outputs:
  TheCreatedS3BucketName:
    Description: Name of the old S3 bucket.
    Value: !Ref <Resource Name>
    Export:
      Name: sensor-processor-v3-dev
```

Import it to other templates:

```
serverlessKinesisFirehoseBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    BucketName: Fn::ImportValue 
        'Fn::Sub': 'sensor-processor-v3-dev'
    LifecycleConfiguration:
    ...
```

Another solution is using random/stack-id in S3 bucket name. You will have many S3 buckets.